# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de objeto em array

Tags: c#, .net, array, nullpointerexception

Estou com um problema. Tenho que fazer um programa de locadora em que vc diz os dados de 5 filmes, e em seguida o programa lista todas as informações!

E é obrigatório fazer uma classe para isso! Eu já fiz a classe `DadosFilme`, e instanciei a variável dados para ir buscar as informações na classe `DadosFilme`

Só que eu fiz a variável dados ser um vetor, e sempre que eu digito o nome do filme no começo do programa já dá esse erro:

> "REFERÊNCIA DE OBJETO NÃO DEFINIDA PARA UMA INSTÂNCIA DE OBJETO"

```
class DadosFilme
    {
        public string NomeFilme;
        public double Duracao;
        public string NomeDiretor;
        public string Categoria;
        public int Ano;

    }

static void Main(string[] args) {
        DadosFilme[] dados = new DadosFilme[6];
        string categoria;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Digite as informações do filme: ");
            Console.Write("Nome do filme.....: ");
            dados[i].NomeFilme = Console.ReadLine(); //É AQUI QUE DÁ O ERRO

            Console.Write("Duração do filme..: ");
            dados[i].Duracao = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Nome do Diretor...: ");
            dados[i].NomeDiretor = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Categoria do filme: ");
            dados[i].Categoria = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Ano de lançamento.: ");
            dados[i].Ano = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            i++;

        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite a sua categoria de filme preferida: ");
        categoria = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Clear();

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Nome do filme............: " + dados[j].NomeFilme);
            Console.WriteLine("Duração do filme.........: " + dados[j].Duracao);
            Console.WriteLine("Nome do Diretor..........: " + dados[j].NomeDiretor);
            Console.WriteLine("Categoria do Filme.......: " + dados[j].Categoria);
            Console.WriteLine("Anop de Lançamento.......: " + dados[j].Ano);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Filmes que pertencem a categoria {0}: ", categoria);

        dados[5].Categoria = categoria;

        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            if (dados[k] == dados[5]) {
                Console.WriteLine(dados[k].NomeFilme);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: mostre a linha que dá erro

Comment: essa mensagem significa que você está tentando usar um objeto nulo, precisa saber onde é esse acesso.

Answer (score 3):

Cada membro do *array* deve ter uma instância da classe `DadosFilme` e não está criando esta instância. Teria que fazer isto antes de poder usar cada item:

```
dados[i] = new DadosFilme();
```

O código tem alguns outros problemas, e poderia ser mais simples. Por exemplo dá erro se houver digitação errada (só encerrei, mas pode fazer o tratamento que quiser, só não deixe o código quebrar, isto é erro de programação). Mudei o `double` para `int` porque isto não faz sentido. Nem entrei no mérito que uma classe normalmente não é criada assim porque deve ser um exercício, mas tenha em mente que isto pode ser problema em código real. Colocar a categoria como se fosse um filme é algo muito errado, mas deixei.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() { 
        DadosFilme[] dados = new DadosFilme[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            dados[i] = new DadosFilme();
            Clear();
            WriteLine("Digite as informações do filme: ");
            Write("Nome do filme.....: ");
            dados[i].NomeFilme = ReadLine();
            Write("Duração do filme..: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out dados[i].Duracao)) return;
            Write("Nome do Diretor...: ");
            dados[i].NomeDiretor = ReadLine();
            Write("Categoria do filme: ");
            dados[i].Categoria = ReadLine();
            Write("Ano de lançamento.: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out dados[i].Ano)) return;
        }
        Clear();
        WriteLine("Digite a sua categoria de filme preferida: ");
        var categoria = ReadLine();
        Clear();
        foreach (var item in dados) {
            WriteLine($"Nome do filme............: {item.NomeFilme}");
            WriteLine($"Duração do filme.........: {item.Duracao}");
            WriteLine($"Nome do Diretor..........: {item.NomeDiretor}");
            WriteLine($"Categoria do Filme.......: {item.Categoria}");
            WriteLine($"Anop de Lançamento.......: {item.Ano}\n\n");
        }
        WriteLine($"Filmes que pertencem a categoria {categoria}: ");
        dados[5] = new DadosFilme();
        dados[5].Categoria = categoria; //isto não faz sentido
        foreach (var item in dados) if (item == dados[5]) WriteLine(item.NomeFilme);
    }
}

public class DadosFilme {
    public string NomeFilme;
    public int Duracao;
    public string NomeDiretor;
    public string Categoria;
    public int Ano;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Movies.cs).

Comment: Vou tentar, valeu Jhow!+.......

Comment: Deu certo, Valeu! mas só esta repetindo 3 vezes ao invés de 5!+.......

Comment: @davidgomezsouza eu até vi um problema que corrigi, mas fiz o teste e está pedindo 5 vezes.

Answer (score 1):

Precisa instanciar cada objeto do vetor dados.

Tenta isso logo depois do for:

```
dados[i] = new DadosFilme();
```

Answer (score 1):

Você criou um array de 6 posições, porém não instanciou o objeto. Basta instanciar o objeto que irá funcionar:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    DadosFilme[] dados = new DadosFilme[6];
    string categoria;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //Adicione essa linha de código que irá funcionar
        dados[i] = new DadosFilme();

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite as informações do filme: ");
        Console.Write("Nome do filme.....: ");
        dados[i].NomeFilme = Console.ReadLine(); //É AQUI QUE DÁ O ERRO

        Console.Write("Duração do filme..: ");
        dados[i].Duracao = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Nome do Diretor...: ");
        dados[i].NomeDiretor = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Categoria do filme: ");
        dados[i].Categoria = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Ano de lançamento.: ");
        dados[i].Ano = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        i++;

    }

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Digite a sua categoria de filme preferida: ");
    categoria = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Clear();

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        Console.WriteLine("Nome do filme............: " + dados[j].NomeFilme);
        Console.WriteLine("Duração do filme.........: " + dados[j].Duracao);
        Console.WriteLine("Nome do Diretor..........: " + dados[j].NomeDiretor);
        Console.WriteLine("Categoria do Filme.......: " + dados[j].Categoria);
        Console.WriteLine("Anop de Lançamento.......: " + dados[j].Ano);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Filmes que pertencem a categoria {0}: ", categoria);

    dados[5].Categoria = categoria;

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        if (dados[k] == dados[5]) {
            Console.WriteLine(dados[k].NomeFilme);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Vou tentar, valeu jhow!+.......

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que uma lista ficaria melhor, então eu faria assim:
primeiro criaria um metodo toString() na sua classe

```
    class DadosFilme {

    public string NomeFilme { get; set; }
    public double Duracao { get; set; }
    public string NomeDiretor { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public int Ano { get; set; }


    public override string ToString() {
        return "Nome do filme: " + NomeFilme +
               "\nDuração: " + Duracao.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
               "\nNome do Diretor: " + NomeDiretor +
               "\nCategoria: " + Categoria +
               "\nAno: " + Ano;
    }
}
```

depois armazenaria td em uma lista e depois mostrava na tela

```
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        List<DadosFilme> listaFilme = new List<DadosFilme>();

        DadosFilme dados = new DadosFilme();
        Console.Write("Nome do filme: ");
        dados.NomeFilme = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Duração do filme: ");
        dados.Duracao = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Nome do diretor: ");
        dados.NomeDiretor = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("categoria do filme: ");
        dados.Categoria = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Ano de lançamento: ");
        dados.Ano = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        listaFilme.Add(dados);

        foreach (DadosFilme item in listaFilme) {

            Console.WriteLine(item);

        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: É uma boa, valeu jhow!+.......